# bootstrap selectpicker selected value

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have an issue with `selectpicker`, when I tried to get selected value, after the page loaded I got value = "null", but when I try to get value after the selected change I got the correct value, what is the issue?

My code is:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  alert($("#level").val());
});

function Change(level){
  alert($(level).val());
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select id="level" onchange="Change(this)" data-style="form-control" class="selectpicker" title="" name="level" style="width: 100%;">   
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not passing any to value to function onload, change this to this.val()

```
 <select id="level" onchange="Change(this.val())" data-style="form-control" class="selectpicker" title="" name="level" style="width: 100%;">   
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
```